# Magento Retrieve products from second website

Tags: product-collection, websites

I am trying to retrieve  products related with my second website with the following code

```
$_products_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$_products_collection->addWebsiteFilter(2); 
$_products_collection->setStoreId(16); 
$_products_collection->addAttributeToSelect("*");
```

The problem is that this collection include only the products that are in website 1 and 2. What i am doing wrong and i can't get products that are only related to the second website?

Answer (score 0):

Just try below code to filter product

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addWebsiteFilter('2')->addAttributeToSelect("*");
```

Answer (score 0):

**You  used wrong function filter collection by store**

**Use array for this case array(2);**

```
 $_products_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$_products_collection->addWebsiteFilter(array(2)); // use array
 $_products_collection->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
```

and Use `addStoreFilter()` function for `get specific store products`

```
$store=Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(16);
 $_products_collection-> addStoreFilter($store);
```

Comment: This solution isn't working. I can retrieve products that are connected two the two websites but i can't load those only connected to the second website.